# How can I write this PHP code in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, phpjs

How can I write this PHP code in JavaScript?

I have no knowledge about JavaScript... :-s

```
<?php
    $pozethumb=scandir("./pics/flori/thumbs");
    $size=count($pozethumb);
    $nrpoze=$size-2;                    
    for($i=2;$i<$size;$i++)
    {
        echo"<img src=\"./pics/flori/thumbs/$pozethumb[$i]\" class=\"thumb\" sou=\"$pozethumb[$i]\" />";
    }                    
?>
```

Comment: PHP is a server-side language, JavaScript usually a client-side one. Client-side JS has no possibility of listing files in a folder. How do you expect this to work? Or do you mean server-side Javascript?

Comment: well i said i have no knowledge about javascript, i thought it could be possible to do this. thnx. i'll modify the php code to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider familiarizing yourself with [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/). It requires you to have a [serverside V8 JS engine](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) installed on the server. This would allow you to use ECMAScript/JavaScript on the server, e.g. list files on the filesystem of the server and query it from the client.

[See the API docs](http://nodejs.org/api.html)

> - fs.readdir(path, [callback])
>     Asynchronous readdir(3). Reads the contents of a directory. The callback gets two arguments (err, files) where files is an array of the names of the files in the directory excluding '.' and '..'.

and

> - fs.readdirSync(path)
>     Synchronous readdir(3). Returns an array of filenames excluding '.' and '..'.

You might also be interested in [phpjs](http://phpjs.org/functions/index), which aims to port PHP functions to PHP *(doesnt have `scandir` though and I'm really not sure what to think of that in general anyway)*.

Answer (score 3):

You can't read files from the server's file system using JavaScript.

Javascript runs on the browser, so you don't have access to server, unless you write some PHP code and AJAX to do that.